# Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 13 - Text Files to Spreadsheet

Tags: python

The [project outline](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter13/):

> Write a program to read in the contents of several text files (you can
> make the text files yourself) and insert those contents into a
> spreadsheet, with one line of text per row. The lines of the first
> text file will be in the cells of column A, the lines of the second
> text file will be in the cells of column B, and so on.
>
> Use the readlines() File object method to return a list of strings,
> one string per line in the file. For the first file, output the first
> line to column 1, row 1. The second line should be written to column
> 1, row 2, and so on. The next file that is read with readlines() will
> be written to column 2, the next file to column 3, and so on.

My solution:

```
# A program to read text files and write it to an Excel file with one line per row
# Usage: python text_to_spreadsheet.py "folder to search for text files" "save location for spreadsheet"

import sys, openpyxl
from pathlib import Path

def main(search_folder, save_path):
    workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet = workbook.active
    for column_index, filename in enumerate(search_folder.glob("*.txt")):
        with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
            for row_index, line in enumerate(text_file.readlines()):
                sheet.cell(row=row_index + 1, column=column_index + 1).value = line.strip()
    workbook.save(save_path)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    search_folder = Path(sys.argv[1]) # the folder with text files to search
    save_path = Path(sys.argv[2]) # the path of the new spreadsheet (must end in .xlsx)
    main(search_folder, save_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not stated any review goals so I will share my thoughts and ideas about your code:

### General

Overall your code looks clean, follows pythonic style and is readable. You are using descriptive variable names and the structure is easy to follow.

### Formatting / PEP8

There are two minor PEP8 violations I spotted:

- [Imports should be on separate lines](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#blank-lines), i.e. `sys` and `openpyxl` should be imported using separate import statements
- [There should be two blank lines before and after a top level function definition](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports)

### Using Argparse

I like the comments describing the command line arguments and the usage of the program. This is also the area in which I think you could improve it the most, because with very little effort you could turn these comments into `argparse` help texts. This does not negatively impact the readability of the program (in my opinion) but helps the user of the program.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from argparse import ArgumentParser

    parser = ArgumentParser(
        description="A program to read text files and write it to an Excel file with one line per row"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "search_folder",
        help="the folder with text files to search",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "save_path",
        help="the path of the new spreadsheet (must end in .xlsx)",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(Path(args.search_folder), Path(args.save_path))
```

When the new code is called with the `--help` flag it outputs the folloing message:

```
usage: test.py [-h] search_folder save_path

A program to read text files and write it to an Excel file with one line per row

positional arguments:
  search_folder  the folder with text files to search
  save_path      the path of the new spreadsheet (must end in .xlsx)

options:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
```

Additionally a usefull error message is generated if not enough or too many arguments are provided.